# dac output stage using single supply?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, dac, single-supply-op-amp

The following is a diagram from a DAC datasheet. It's an output stage for a high end audio DAC which has differential outputs.

What would be the best way to implement this when only a single supply voltage is available (say 9v) rather than a dual supply?

Thanks
B

[image]

Comment: The same way, but take the presently grounded end of the 4.7k (the 'other' R2 if everything was properly numbered) to your reference Vrail/2 voltage, and ground the opamp -ve supply. Aout now comes out with reference to Vrail/2.

Comment: @Neil_UK with reference to Vrail/2 = put an AC coupling cap at analog out to get rid of the DC offset?

Comment: If you want the analogue output ground-referenced, then yes, you will need a cap to support the offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have a single supply, it's very likely that AOUT+ and AOUT- aren't symmetric around 0V, but around some offset voltage V_bias.

That means that you can replace the "ground" in your schematic simply by a virtual ground in the middle between your supply voltage and 0V.

You typically just create such a ground by using relatively low-valued resistors in a voltage divider between Vcc and 0V. The effect of that, however, is that you waste a lot of energy across these.

It's often easier to use a linear voltage regulator (think of the ubiquitous LM78XX regulators) or a fixed voltage reference followed by an opamp in voltage follower config.

The actual voltage of that virtual ground isn't critical – it's just important that it's **stable**, and you have to realize that what is called "Analog Out" in your circuit is relative to that voltage – so, that virtual ground will be what your speaker will be driven against (i.e. the black cable of the speaker should connect to that, not 0V!).

In other words, there's a lot of drawbacks to doing this.

This is 2016, not 1972. Just grab one of the literally hundreds ([TI](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/audio/overview.page), [Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/audio/speaker-amplifiers.html), [Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/en/products/audio-video/audio-amplifiers/class-d-audio-amplifiers.html), [ST micro](http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/audio-ics/audio-amplifiers.html), [NXP](http://www.nxp.com/products/media-and-audio-processing/audio-amplifiers:MC_71458),  [ON semi](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/parametrics.do?id=62) and many, many more)  of audio amplifiers designed to work with single supplies and use a schematic from their datasheet or application notes – you'll notice that you can typically find high-valued capacitors at the audio output, which solves the whole bias voltage problem.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - when using a single supply opamp in the above schematic, won't the required changes be the same as when using a virtual ground?

Comment: no, they won't, because you don't have an output that is referenced to a virtual ground, but to the actual ground. Hence my recommendation to **follow the circuits from datasheets and app notes** from single-supply amplifiers. And if you're doing audio, just use a dedicated audio amplifiere.

Comment: thanks, what about using something like the tps65130 to generate +/- 15v from the 9v and then use a low noise LDO to filter the +/- 15v and power the opamps?

Comment: I will **not** continue to help you design something that is unnecessarily complex. **If you want an audio amplifier driven from a single supply, use a single supply audio amplifier IC and not a dual-supply opamp**, especially if you're not an experienced circuit designer.

Comment: ok, I understand. Can you give me one or two examples of single supply audio opamps? I have been searching for specific parts without much luck. Most of them assume dual supplies.